# Try to use DotLiquid with c#

Tags: c#, dotliquid

I was unable to excute example in : http://dotliquidmarkup.org/try-online with C#.
I have the same example and try to execute it with following code :

```
var template = DotLiquid.Template.Parse(myTemplate);
Message.Body = template.Render(DotLiquid.Hash.FromAnonymousObject(user));
```

Where myTemplate is exactly the same as in example :

```
<p>{{ user.name | upcase }} has to do:</p>
<ul>
{% for item in user.tasks -%}
  <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
{% endfor -%}
</ul>
```

But when hit Render i receive error :
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
and the inner message is : Parameter count mismatch.

My data type as i told is the same like in example :

```
public class User : DotLiquid.Drop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And i create object like that :

```
var user = new User
{
    Name = "Tim Jones",
    Tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        new Task { Name = "Documentation" },
        new Task { Name = "Code comments" }
    }
};
```

I can`t figure it out what is the issue with my code. 
Will appreciate any help ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Hash.FromAnonymousObject` which expects an anonymous object (as its name implies).

So pass an anonymous object:

```
template.Render(DotLiquid.Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new
        {
            user = new User
            {
                Name = "Tim Jones",
                Tasks = new List<Task>
                {
                    new Task { Name = "Documentation" },
                    new Task { Name = "Code comments" }
                }
            }
        }));
```

Or, in your case (I haven't tested, but this should work):

```
template.Render(DotLiquid.Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { user = this.user }));
```