# Dotliquid Template Render outputs filepath

Tags: c#, dotliquid

I am currently trying to work with DotLiquid in C# and I've observed a behavior that I don't quite understand. Since I am not very familiar with C#, I cannot say for sure if my issue is with C# itself, or DotLiquid, so please bear with me. =)

I have a very basic `index.liquid` that I am trying to pass a `Table`-object to.
For the sake of getting started, I've overridden `toString()` to simply create a representation, for now, I'll later want to work with the actual object. When trying to work with the template, this is what I do:

```
public static void createHTML(DataTable table)
{
    string templatePath = @"C:\Path\To\index.liquid";
    var template = Template.Parse(templatePath);
    template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new
    {
        table = DataMapper.createTable(table).toString()
    });

    using (StreamWrite file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Some\Path\test.html"))
    {
        file.write(template.Render());
    }
}
```

Now, when I open this newly created `test.html`, all it contains is `C:\Path\To\index.liquid`, meaning I am somehow not loading my template correctly. Looking at [Try to use DotLiquid with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431230/try-to-use-dotliquid-with-c-sharp)
I would have thought that I am loading the template correctly and using  `File.ReadAllText(templatePath));` showed me that `templatePath` is pointing to the correct file.

This shows me that I'm not understanding something very basic about `Template.Parse()` or `Template.Render()` where the source code doesn't provide me with the insight I'm missing, so hopefully, you can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully saving others from getting tripped up on this. The real reason why the output is the filepath is because **Template.Parse(string source)** expects the actual template *contents*, not a file path.

In order to accomplish what you are attempting, you need to use it this way:

```
Template template = Template.Parse(File.ReadAllText(templatePath));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without the content of `index.liquid`, but there is already one thing to fix: you are calling `Render` two times, and the second without your object.

Try this:

```
public static void createHTML(DataTable table)
{
    string templatePath = @"C:\Path\To\index.liquid";
    var template = Template.Parse(templatePath);

    using (StreamWrite file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Some\Path\test.html"))
    {
        file.write(template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new
        {
            table = DataMapper.createTable(table).toString()
        })));
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, please update your question to add the content of `index.liquid`.